# regex for multiple imei validation

Tags: c#, regex

i am making a regex for imei, but i want it should optionally take multiple imei, example
123456789123456 this will be accepted and if commo i.e , will be at the end then it should also allow comma but only after the 15th digit not before the 15th digit,
i want it should validate this

123456789123456

and if comma is added it should only at after the 15th digit and if comma added it should validate like

123456789123456,123456789123456,123456789123456

a comma between all the 15th digit will be accepted not before 15th digit
such multiple imei
i had made this
^[0-9]{15,15}|[,]$
but it is not working as it allows comma , before the 15th digit, which i dont want, how can i modify my regex? or i want to change the whole regex?
i am using such code

```
         Regex regex = new Regex("^[0-9]{15,15}|[,]$");
        if (regex.IsMatch(textBox2.Text))
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return true;
        }
```

Comment: for multiple imei, i have a textbox for which will take one imei or if comma added it should take multiple imei like this
123456789123456,123456789123456,123456789123456

Comment: if you are looking for other solutions than regEx try this http://www.dreamincode.net/code/snippet1033.htm

Comment: Do you want to accept `123456789123456,` or `123456789123456,123456789123456,` (extra comma at the end) or `123456789123456, 123456789123456` (spaces in between)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like this:

```
^\d{15}(,\d{15})*$
```

It will accept 1 sequence of 15 digits, or multiple sequences of 15 digits, separated by commas. Note that spaces and extra commas are not allowed.

If you want to allow spaces, you should remove all spaces before validation.

Comment: no sir i dont want to allow spaces, its exaclty what i am looking for, you are the regex hero
:)

Comment: ohkay. i dont know whats your name. its odd to assume the id as ur name. but anyways if i want to further modify your reges for other use like the string should be minimum 2 numbers or alphabets or mixiture of numbers and alphabets and maximum of 12, and it should contain no comma but at the end a comma is there then it should work for furthe same string, like it was for imei, same but the needs is changed to minimum 2 and maximum 12 and it should be mixture of alphabets and numbers then what should be the modification in your regex? ^[a-bA-Z0-9]{2,12}(,[a-bA-Z0-9]{2,12})*$
is this correct?

Comment: like it should accept
nokia
or it should accept nokia,T-MOBILE,china1245,sony erricson

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,12}(,[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,12})*$` (note that I changed a-b to a-z). The regex seems OK *if I understand your requirement correctly*, but please check the documentation or whatever for the IMEI - otherwise, you will allow invalid one to be entered.

Comment: sir i have implemented your regex ^\d{15}(,\d{15})*$
as
 Regex regex = new Regex("^\d{15}(,\d{15})*$");
but the error is coming ""unrecognize escape sequence"

Comment: What I gave is raw regex. You may need to escape the \.

Comment: @shariq_khan: Check this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

Comment: you may need to escape the \.
how to avoid that?

Comment: @shariq_khan: Read the article. You can use the verbatim string literal `@"^\d{15}(,\d{15})*$"` so you don't have to escape \

Comment: i have made this ^[a-zA-Z0-9- ]{2,25}(,[a-zA-Z0-9- ]{2,25})*$ is this for my need?
nokia,T-MOBILE,china1245,sony erricson does it have any side effects?

Comment: @shariq_khan: Are you sure you want the length to be **anything** between 2-25 characters? And it seems to add space and `-` in there - you can match something totally invalid such as 25 `-`. Ask a new question, specify all the requirement **clearly**, since the requirement has changed too much from the current question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162839/how-to-transfer-the-text-from-dynamically-generated-user-control-to-a-textbox
CAN YOU HELP ME  PLEASE

Answer (score 4):

15 digits, than a pattern like (comma and 15 digits) n-times:

```
^[0-9]{15}(,[0-9]{15})*$
```